# Is $X^{E} \equiv X \;(\text{mod}\; n)$ a potential problem in the RSA cryptosystem?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, cryptography

This is Exercises 11 from Section 7.3 of the [book "Abstract Algebra:
Theory and Applications" (aata-20180801) by Thomas W. Judson](http://abstract.ups.edu/download/aata-20180801-sage-8.2.pdf).

> Find integers $n$, $E$, $X$ such that
>   $$ X^{E} \equiv X \;(\text{mod}\; n). $$
>   Is this a potential problem in the RSA cryptosystem?

What does the "potential problem" mean in this problem? Is it related to the Iterated Encryption Attack described [in this article](https://math.boisestate.edu/~liljanab/ISAS/course_materials/AttacksRSA.pdf)?

Comment: Imagine that the secret message you wanted to encrypt happened to be equal to $X$, what would it get encrypted to?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you find integers $n$, $E$, $X$ such that
$$ X^{E} \equiv X \;(\text{mod}\; n). $$ Then;

$$ X^{E} -X = k \cdot n \quad\text{ for some } k\in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Take out $X$

$$ X ( X^{E-1} -1) = k \cdot n \quad (= k \cdot p \cdot q)$$

Now, calculate $\gcd(X,n)$ and $\gcd(X^{E-1} -1,n)$.

If you are lucky, you might find $p$ and $q$.

Comment: You might just find factors of $k$ instead...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thanks, I think, in the worst case $X$ is equal to a divisor $t$ of $k$ and $X^{E-1}-1,n$ is equal to $tn$.